# ajax form error

Tags: ajax, forms, duplicates, send

After I push the button, I am getting the following warning and form is duplicated. Any error in the code?

[image: http://divran.com/s/upload/images/fso5xclhcdpbwamj153s.gif]

```
           <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
            <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
            <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1254" />
            <script src="jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <title>jquery AJAX</title>
            <script language="javascript">
                $(document).ready(function(){
                            var name    = $("#name").val();
                            var sname   = $("#sname").val();
                            var email   = $("#email").val();

                        $("#b1").click(function(){          
                            $.ajax({
                                type    :"POST",
                                URL     :"save.php",
                                data    :"name="+name+"&sname="+sname+"&email="+email,
                                dataType:"text",
                                success :function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {                           
                                            if (data == 'success'){
                                                $("#res").html("sonuc :"+data); 
                                            }else{
                                                $("#res").html(data +":"+textStatus+":"+jqXHR);
                                                }
                                }
                            });             
                        }); 
                    });

            </script>
            </head>
            <body>
            <input type="text" id="name"/><br />
            <input type="text" id="sname"/><br />
            <input type="text" id="email"/><br />
            <button id="b1">send</button>
            <div id="res"></div>
            </body>
            </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's doing exactly what it's supposed to do. The error is in this part:

```
success :function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {                           
    if (data == 'success'){
        $("#res").html("sonuc :"+data); 
    }else{
        $("#res").html(data +":"+textStatus+":"+jqXHR);
    }
}
```

This callback is triggered whenever the AJAX call was successful, but then you check if the `data` key equals `success`, which it is not and thus the else clause is now triggered (as can be seen on your screenshot). I believe what you are actaully trying to check is if the `textStatus` was a success instead. So, replace:

```
if (data == 'success'){
```

With this:

```
if (textStatus == 'success') {
```

And you should get a `sonuc :` followed by the data as a result.

**Please note** that the entire if/else is actually not useful though, since this is already the `success` callback that is only returned when the AJAX request was a success. You might want to put this:

```
$("#res").html(data +":"+textStatus+":"+jqXHR);
```

Into the error callback, so you'll get:

```
success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {                           
    $("#res").html("sonuc :"+data); 
},
error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    $("#res").html(data +":"+textStatus+":"+jqXHR);
}
```

Comment: i did it like you said but when i clicked button it recreate form like you see obove image. it doesnt run correctly. i can not callback result